# hive UDF to fetch tables values inside UDF code

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, user-defined-functions

I have a requirement to get column value of an table .
Lets say i  need to get category of Each material based on material number(which is a different table ) passed as input to UDF .
Category is stored in Different table .
[Category Table here][1]

```
material_num Category 
123          Chemicals
124          pack
```

I would like to implement  UDF code like below

```
function getCategory(matNum String)
{
get category from category table based on material number 

Return category 
}
```

When I call from hive query

```
select getCategory("123")
```

it should return **chemicals** as output
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lbs5.png

Comment: why not to join with Category table without udf at all?

Comment: used many places . if something changes . i would like to change only in one part